# Cassandra Database Datastax Coordinator node timed out?

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I am receiving the following error.

```
cassandra.ReadTimeOut: Error from server: code =1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message = Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={consistency: 'LOCAL_ONE',required_responses": 1, 'received_responses": 0}
```

this is the query it is running

```
query = "select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table where timestamp >= last_hour and <= current_hour ALLOW FILTERING"
```

last_hour and current_hour are variables that grab the current time, and the last 1 hour time.

then I do

```
queryResult = session.execute_async(query)
```

and receive the error.

It sometimes just succesfully runs, and others it throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for it is that you're incorrectly use Cassandra. It works fast only when you're performing read of specific partition only. But in your case you have a condition on the non-partition column (or even if it's a partition, you can't do the range query on it), and this causes Cassandra to scan all data in the database (on all nodes) to get you result. And with reasonable amount of data, this takes significant amount of time, and lead to timeout.

The first rule of Cassandra data modelling is "if you use ALLOW FILTERING, you're doing something wrong"...

I recommend to take DS201 & DS220 courses on [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) to understand how Cassandra works, and how to design data model for it.